# Rx Subject Vs GoF Subject

Tags: rxjs, system.reactive, gang-of-four

How the [Rx Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173(v=vs.103).aspx) and the [Subject](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jwood/head-first-design-patterns-part-1-observer-pattern) in GandOfFour Observer pattern are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some overlap:

- GoF Subject: Subscribe handler, unsubscribe handler, send notification to handlers
- Rx Observable: Subscribe handler of type T,  (implicitly unsubscribe via subscription disposable)
- Rx Observer: Handler that receives notification of type T (or error, or end)
- Rx Subject: Observable + Observer for some type T

So they support the same basic operations. I would assume Rx Team chose their name based on GoF usage. Rx Team though clearly wanted to split the functions of 'Subject' into sender and receiver: The emphasis in Rx is observables, not subjects.